# Below given Selenium Code for Excel is not Working

Tags: java, selenium

```
package poi;

import java.io.*;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class Demo

{

  public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException

  {

    String temp ="C:/santosh_chikne/Selenium Script/test.xlsx"; 

    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(temp);

    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try as following:

```
 String temp ="C:/santosh_chikne/Selenium Script/test.xlsx"; 

FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(temp);

HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
HSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
Row row = sh.getRow(1);
Cell cell = row.getCell(1);

String valueFromXl = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

Comment: The above code gives an error "Cannot find Symbol HSSFWorkbook and Cell"

Comment: Are you using     poi-ooxml   or      poi ?

Comment: i am using poi-ooxml

Comment: So, change HSSFWorkbook to XSSFWorkbook